# Кликнуть Checkbox на странице открытой в WebBrowser -e

Tags: webbrowser, checkbox, delphi-7

Добрый день. В веббраузер загружена хтмл-страница, там несколько слов и напротив каждого checkbox.В мемо тоже список слов, нужно кликнуть на checkbox если слова на странице и в мемо совпадают. использую вот такой код:

```
begin
  Docc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  Buttons := Docc.all.tags('checkbox') as IHTMLElementCollection;
  for i := 0 to Buttons.length - 1 do
     begin
    Button := Buttons.item(i, EmptyParam) as IHTMLElement;
    if AnsiSameText(Trim(Button.innerText), Memo2.Text) then
begin
      Button.click;
      Break;
end;
 end;
  end;
```

Если в мемо 1 слово то работает, а если несколько то нет. Подскажите как сделать чтоб нажимались несколько checkbox -ов если допустим 2 или больше слов совпали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Memo2.Text` это весь текст из мемо одной строкой. Если в мемо несколько строк, то в `text` они будут разделены символами конца строки. `AnsiSameText` сработает только если строки одинаковой длинны и все символы до последнего совпали (без учета регистра).
Делите текст в мемо на слова и пробуйте использовать `Pos` вместо `AnsiSameText`.

Comment: спасибо,разобрался!

Comment: @stud отлично :) Осталось выбрать ответ, который помог и пометить его как принятый.